# Continue keyword in recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I have come across the below code while searching some answers.

```
public static void recurse(Scanner in, HashMap<String, Integer> oldMap) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = null;
    if (oldMap == null) 
        map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    else
        map = new HashMap<String, Integer>(oldMap);
    while (in.hasNext) {
        String s = in.nextLine();
        if (s.startsWith("[")) {
            recurse(in, map);
            continue;
        }
        if (s.startsWith("]")) {
            break;
        }
        String[] split = s.split(" ");
        if (s.startsWith("print")) {
            System.out.println(map.containsKey(split[1]) ? map.get(split[1]) : 0);
            continue;
        }
        int x = 0;
        try {
            x = Integer.parse(split[1]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            x = map.containsKey(split[1]) ? map.get(split[1]) : 0;
        }
        map.put(split[0], x);
    }
}
```

Can somebody please explain me , why the person has used continue just after recursive call. It seems to be that the continue will not be processed because each time the recursion call will be processed.

Comment: Hi Louis,I agree but then why the continue has been mentioned inside the if statement.I mean, if i remove continue then will it work as it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's true that the recursive call will be processed — but then, eventually, the recursive call will return. (Unless it either raises an exception or enters an infinite loop, that is.) After the recursive call returns, the `continue` statement is executed.

It might help you to play with a simpler example of recursion:

```
public void printOneToN(int n) {
    if(n > 1) {
        printOneToN(n - 1);
    }
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

As you can see by running (say) `printOneToN(10)`, after each recursive call, control returns to its caller. A recursive call does not replace its caller.

Comment: When you say recusrive call will return, you mean once the recursion loop ends by itself then it will return to original if statement from where it got called. In that case , i have another doubt , before returning the if condition has to be satisfied too.Sorry but i am confused...

Comment: @manishpro: it doesn't "return to the original if statement", it finishes executing the line where it was called, which is already within the if.

Answer (score 1):

`continue` has nothing to do with the recursive call; its effect is to skip the rest of the contents of the `while` loop and go straight back to `in.hasNext()`.